# How do i do the right to use "NOT IN" in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

how can i fix it this problem, because i want to find the ID lost and bring me back to use the ID lost, i did this code but doesn't work because it returns nothing.

**PHP**

```
$query = 'SELECT (folio+1) FROM detalles_devoluciones WHERE (folio+1) NOT IN (SELECT folio FROM detalles_devoluciones) limit 1;';
$resultado = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$total = mysql_num_rows($resultado);    
     while ($c = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){        
               $folio = $c['folio'];    
               echo $folio;        
     }
```

I test this:

```
print_r($folio);
```

and nothing too

**UPDATE:**

**HTML**

```
<label for="folio">Folio:</label>
      <input type="text" value="<?=$c["folio"]?>" name="folio"  disabled/>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$c["folio"]?>" name="folio"  />
```

or

```
<label for="folio">Folio:</label>
      <input type="text" value="<?=$folio?>" name="folio"  disabled/>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$folio?>" name="folio"  />
```

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: remove `;` which is in query and check.

Comment: the error is returns nothing in the input value="<?=$folio?>", i mean in this input is blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Why are you looking for folio+1?

The syntax of your sql-statement looks correct to me, have you tried to send it directly to the database via phpmyadmin or console?

btw you should not use the mysql_* extension as it is deprecated. Better use mysqli_* or PDOs functions to handle the database-operations.http://php.net/manual/de/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

edit:
To fetch the column it would be good to use an alias for the selected column.

```
SELECT (folio+1) AS folio FROM...
```

So you can access it over the index 'folio' after fetching the result

Comment: i did this proof to use before to implement in PHP, i show the example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c766/11 i want to find the ID or Folio lost and bring me back to use the ID or Folio

Comment: yes i send it directly to the database via phpmyadmin

Comment: It looks to me like he is trying to get "gaps" in data; and the query looks like it should always get the "next" useable folio value as well.

Comment: I'm stupid. Please give your selected Column an alias

Comment: yes it works with your little code, i have to fetch the column `SELECT (folio+1) AS folio FROM...`